# Line with specific angle

Tags: c#, arcobjects

I've created a line by mouse click event when I click on the second point I need two lines at an angle of 28 degrees from the first line how should I do it?.
[image]

IPoint point1;
        IPoint point2;

```
     protected override void OnMouseDown(ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool.MouseEventArgs arg)
    {

        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IGraphicsContainer gContiner = mxdoc.FocusMap as IGraphicsContainer;
        IDisplayTransformation dispTransformation =
        mxdoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation;


        if (point1 == null)
        {


            point1 = dispTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
            IMarkerElement markerElement = new MarkerElementClass();

            IElement element = (IElement)markerElement;
            element.Geometry = point1;
            gContiner.AddElement(element, 0);
            mxdoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics,
            null, null);
        }
        else if (point2 == null)
        {

            point2 = dispTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
            IMarkerElement markerElement = new MarkerElementClass();

            IElement element = (IElement)markerElement;
            element.Geometry = point2;
            gContiner.AddElement(element, 0);
            mxdoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics,
            null, null);
        }

        else
        {
            //
            IPolyline polyline = new PolylineClass();
            IPointCollection pointColl = polyline as IPointCollection;

            pointColl.AddPoint(point1);
            pointColl.AddPoint(point2);




            // Create a line element, this is the graphic that will get added to container

            IElement element = new LineElement();
            element.Geometry = polyline;

            ILineElement lineElement;
            lineElement = element as ILineElement;

            gContiner.AddElement(element, 0);
            mxdoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, null, null);


        }
    }
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can you reduce it to illustrate the problem you are having or at least state where the issue is.

Comment: Hi I reduce it please check it